# Is the space of probability measures on a compact set is compact w.r.t Wasserstein metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $C \subseteq X$ compact. Let $\Delta (C)$ be the set of all Borel probability measures on $C$. We endow $\Delta(C)$ with Wasserstein distance $W_p$ for some $p \ge 1$. Then $(\Delta(C), W_p)$ is a metric space by [Proposition 2.2](https://lchizat.github.io/files2020ot/lecture3.pdf).

- Is $(\Delta(C), W_p)$ compact?
- If the condition $C$ is compact is not sufficient, can $C$ is finite implies $(\Delta(C), W_p)$ is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence in $\Delta(C)$. It is obviously tight because $\mu_n(K)=1\ge1-\varepsilon$ for the compact $K:=C$ and for all $n\ge1$ and $\varepsilon>0$.
By [Prokhorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem), we know that $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ has some limit point $\mu$ w.r.t. the topology of weak convergence. By [Skorokhod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), there exist a probabiltiy space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ and random variables $X,X_1,X_2,\ldots:\Omega\to C$ such that $X$ has law $\mu$, $X_n$ has law $\mu_n$ for every $n\ge1$ and $$d(X_n,X)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\quad\text{$\mathbb P$-a.s.}$$
Now because $C$ is compact, there exists a constant $a>0$ such that $d(X_n,X)\le a$, thus $d(X_n,X)^p\le a^p$ for every $n\ge1$. Hence $$\mathbb E[d(X_n,X)^p]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$ by dominated convergence.
Thus we have couplings $\gamma_n\in\Pi(\mu_n,\mu)$ such that $$\left(\int d(x,y) ^p\,\mathrm d\gamma_n(x,y)\right)^{\!\frac1p}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\:0.$$
Since $W_p(\mu_n,\mu)$ is the infimum of the left-hand side over $\Pi(\mu_n,\mu)$, we deduce that $$W_p(\mu_n,\mu)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0,$$
which means that $\mu$ is also a limit point of $(\mu_n)_{n\ge1}$ for the Wasserstein-$p$ metric. Hence $(\Delta(C),W_p)$ is compact.

Comment: At the first line, why "By Prokhorov's theorem, we know that ()≥1 has some limit point  w.r.t. the topology of weak convergence" is true? Prokehorov's theorem only claims the result when  ()≥1  is tight and is not true for a general sequence of measures.

Comment: @Shunan Sheng, it is true here because $C$ is a compact metric space. See [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures#Compact_spaces).

Comment: Thanks. However, it only suggests that a single probability measure is tight when C is compact metric space, whereas in the context above, we refer to a collection of probability measures and the tightness is now uniform tightness.

Comment: @ShunanSheng The Wikipedia article I just referred to clearly states “If $X$ is a metrisable compact space, then every **collection** of (possibly complex) measures on $X$ is tight.” You can check in the reference “Probability measures on metric spaces” of Parthasarathy that my claim is true: a sequence of probability measures on a compact metric space is automatically tight. In fact, there is equivalence between compactness of $C$ and compactness (for the weak topology) of $\Delta(C)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: I just realized we may directly call the Prokhorov theorem. By tightness of $\Delta(C)$, we have $\Delta(C)$ is precompact, hence compact as it is closed.

Comment: @ShunanSheng: Yes, this is (I think) the argument I use. But this is w.r.t. the topology of weak convergence. To obtain compactness for $W_p$, we need a kind of uniform integrability argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I originally thought it came from the equivalence between sequential compactness and compactness in a metric space.